# Downgrade from Wily to Trusty

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I've upgraded from Ubuntu Trusty to Wily using

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Is there a way to downgrade to Trusty? I found a few software packages I cannot install.

Comment: what do you mean by "cannot install?". Solve the actual problem, not the consequences.

Comment: The installation packages are only available for 14.04. So I can't not solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **backup Data**

Launch Software and from System Settings and on the Updates tab, disable "Pre-released update.

Create a file called "99-downgrade-proposed" under /etc/apt/preferences.d/

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/99-downgrade-proposed
```

And in this file, paste the following:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=saucy
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=saucy-updates
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=saucy-security
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=saucy-backports
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release a=saucy-proposed
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Replace "saucy" with your Ubuntu version in the file above. Then save the file.

Start the downgrade by using the commands below:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```